# How to run a WebForms page and an MVC page in different files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

when i try to do this and load the webforms page, i get this error, even tho the path is correct. what can i do to get past this? i've tried running the aspx page from the root as well. nada.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/Home/FileUploadFrame.aspx

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30128; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30128.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web.config in the Views folder that prevents its contents from being viewed directly.  Instead, put your "public" ASPX pages in a different folder and reference them from there.  You probably don't want "Views/Home" or whatever in the page URL anyway.

Answer (score 1):

All aspx pages inside the Views folder cannot be served directly. There's a web.config file at the root of this folder which prevents this. If you want to serve classic WebForms pages they should be placed outside the Views folder.